# Python: How to import the absolute minimum needed for Matplotlib?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, python-import

I have a small project that uses matplotlib to display a wafer map of die. I am "compiling" the single-file Python (2.7) into an executable using PyInstaller with the --onefile option, so that non-Python users at the company can execute it in Windows.

The executable takes quite a while to load, up to 15s. As a workaround, I removed all the wafer-map plotting capabilities of the program and built a "Lite" version. This Lite version runs in <1s, as it should. In addition, the Lite version's .exe is 85% smaller (as expected).

So it looks like the Matplotlib stuff is bloating the exe and is making it take a long time to load.

Here's my thought process:
I should be able to get the file size down and decrease the load time if I only import the modules I use rather than all of matplotlib.pyplot. I assume that the `import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot` line is importing a whole bunch of extra stuff that I'm not using, such as scatterplots.

Here's my question:
**How can I only import the parts of matplotlib that I use?**

Here's my (relevant) code, with a lot of the fluff (like line colors) removed. Also, please ignore the lack of PEP8 conformity - this was written before I decided to follow it :-)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import matplotlib.patches

fig = pyplot.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax.axis([xAxisMin, xAxisMax, yAxisMin, yAxisMax])
die = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle(coords, dieX, dieY)
ax.add_patch(die)
arc = matplotlib.patches.Arc((0, 0),
                             width=exclDia, height=exclDia, angle=-90,
                             theta1=ang, theta2=-ang)
flat = matplotlib.lines.Line2D([-flatX, flatX],
                               [flatY, flatY])
# Extra code that actually adds everything to the figure
fig.show()
```

So it looks like I'm using only:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.figure
matplotlib.patches.Rectangle
matplotlib.patches.Arc
matplotlib.lines.Line2D
```

However, those above are not individual modules in matplotlib (to my knowledge) - they are classes of their parent module (patches, lines, pyplot), so I can't just `import matplotlib.patches.Arc' or anything.

So. What's my next step?

Comment: Matplotlib is pretty heavy. You could try compressing it with [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/). Could you set this up as a webservice.

Comment: Definitely do not import `pyplot`.  There is no explicit design goal in mpl of enabling this so I do not think it will be easy.

Comment: In my experience, when importing matplotlib, an *.exe file made with py2exe was A LOT faster to load than with PyInstaller.

Comment: @Blender I could try setting it up as a webservice, but I have no experience with that so it would take some time. Worth a shot though.